# EasterSunday replacement in Mathematica 10

Tags: date-and-time

The Calendar package, now obsolete, had functionality for "special dates"; in particular, `EasterSunday[]`. The documentation says it's been subsumed into the Wolfram Language. But it hasn't, at least not to any meaningful degree that I can see. How would I, for example, get the date of Easter Sunday from 1950 - 2050 in a useful form (i.e. something that gives me the equivalent of `EasterSunday[#] & /@ Range[1950, 2050]`? Free form input is very bad at doing things like this in a straightforward way. I don't care if Easter Sunday 2032 is the 91st anniversary of the Battle of Cape Matapan, I really don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DataPaclets`CalendarDataDump`EasterSunday /@ Range[1950, 2050]
DataPaclets`CalendarDataDump`EasterSundayGreekOrthodox /@ Range[1950, 2050]
```

Comment: Might as well include ``DataPaclets`CalendarDataDump`EasterSundayGreekOrthodox``

Comment: I think you made the cardinal sin of adding a superfluous `Function`. :o)

Comment: I just copied the OP's code and added the context.  My family is about and I didn't think... :(

Comment: Well, this works, but I do not regard it as a step forward. Directly querying the contents of curated data is a pretty opaque (and sparsely documented) way of going about things. I guess it answers the question, though.

Answer (score 9):

For reference, here is a *Mathematica* implementation of [this algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/013487a0) from an anonymous source, and reproduced in a number of other references (e.g. Meeus):

```
SetAttributes[easter, Listable];
easter[y_Integer] := Module[{y19 = Mod[y, 19], b, c, d, e, h, i, k, l},
       {b, c} = QuotientRemainder[y, 100];
       {d, e} = QuotientRemainder[b, 4]; {i, k} = QuotientRemainder[c, 4];
       h = Mod[19 y19 + b - d - Quotient[b + 1 - Quotient[b + 8, 25], 3] + 15, 30];
       l = Mod[2 e + 2 i - h - k + 32, 7];
       Prepend[QuotientRemainder[h + l - 7 Quotient[y19 + 11 (h + 2 l), 451] +
                                 114, 31] + {0, 1}, y]]
```

Test:

```
Table[DataPaclets`CalendarDataDump`EasterSunday[k], {k, 1950, 2000}] ===
easter[Range[1950, 2000]]
   True
```

---

As a belated bonus, here is a compact implementation of the *computus* for Greek Orthodox Easter, based on Meeus's version:

```
SetAttributes[easterGreek, Listable];
easterGreek[y_Integer] := Module[{p, q, r, u},
            {p, q, r} = Mod[y, {19, 7, 4}]; u = Mod[19 p + 16, 30];
            u = u + Mod[4 q + 2 r + 6 u, 7] + Quotient[y, 100] - Quotient[y, 400] - 12;
            {y, 4 + Boole[u > 30], Mod[u, 30, 1]}]
```

This should work for the years 1500-5100.

Answer (score 7):

Another undocumented interface similar to the one in [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2)'s answer

```
Developer`CalendarData[{#}, "Easter"] & /@ Range[1950, 2050]
```

Also, while the Calendar package has been deprecated, it is still present in the layout, in other words it is still possible to use `EasterSunday`

```
Needs["Calendar`"]

EasterSunday /@ Range[1950, 2050]
```